# How to get information / help for pyomo functions, methods etc

Tags: documentation, pyomo

First of all I am new to python and pyomo (but got some basic knowlege in Matlab, C, R, and some hardware orientated languages).
I am looking for some kind of documentation for pyomo, something like the help function in other languages but i didn´t find it yet.
For eg. I want to know what type and structure the arguments passed to into param() or .create-instance should have.
There are various examples but I am not able to interpret and adapt them to my case.

```
help(pyomo.create_instance())

AttributeError: module 'pyomo' has no attribute 'create_instance'
```

My concrete problem I will present in a different post, but in general I am struggeling finding informations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, some useful resources:

- pyomo documentation: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
- pyomo website: http://www.pyomo.org/
- pyomo forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pyomo-forum

Finally, from inside your IDE/notebook, you can still use `help` and `dir`, but you have to make sure you are using them on functions/methods that actually exist, and that you call it on the method, not its result.

As per the message you receive, `pyomo.create_instance` does not exist. `create_instance` is a method of `pyomo.environ.AbstractModel`, so you should use `help(pyomo.environ.AbstractModel)` (notice that there is not parenthesis since we are not calling the function/method).
To clarify this, in Matlab there is no distinction between writing `some_function_name` and `some_function_name()`: the function is *called* (executed) anyway. In Python, `some_function_name` gives you the function as an `object`, whereas `some_function_name()` actually *calls* the function.
As you can imagine, `help` works on the function *object*, not on its results.

As a final comment, 99% of the things you actually want to use from pyomo are located inside `pyomo.environ` (unless you want to use the newer but less stable `kernel` library). What I usually do is start with `from pyomo import environ as pe` so that I have all I need available without typing `pyomo.environ` a million times.

Answer (score 1):

the way to look, for what I was looking for the syntax would be:

```
help(model.create_instance)
```